# What can we use for rapid display and update of large numbers of simple objects?

Tags: java, 3d, real-time, modeling, jmonkeyengine

We think there are potentially a number of technologies that might work for us - Java3D, Google Sketchup, JavaFX or gaming framework, and probably many we're not familiar with.

We're getting ready to build an app that will need to be able to display large numbers of simple objects in three dimensions.  Say, a couple thousand wireframe boxes, and allow us to pan, rotate and zoom easily and smoothly.  We're primarily a java shop, so a java solution would probably be preferred over other technologies, just because that's what we're strong in.

We want drag&drop and object resizing with the mouse.  We also want to re-position the boxes or other objects based on event feeds from an external application.  So, we might want to re-position hundreds of the boxes a few times a second.

What technologies can actually get this done?

Our legacy app does this with Java 3D, but we'd like to consider what's suitable for the next generation version.

We like something that's a littler higher-level than Java3d.

Edit:  In the end, we used jMonkeyEngine, and that did the trick for us.

Answer (score 1):

A few thousand wire-frame boxes can be rendered at many frames per second with just about anything. Using 3d hardware acceleration, these could also be rendered as solid in a z-buffer at completely interactive frame rates. I don't think the image you describe is going to help in making the decision. Pick something that's easy to use.

Comment: Good advice.  Java3d equates to a lot of code for the required functionality.  What would you suggest that might reduce the amount of code required relative to Java3D?